# 'runtimes' Folder after Publishing a .Net Core App to Azure Publish Via VS Online

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

What is the purpose of the 'runtimes' folder that gets published along with all my project files?  I have a VS Online account, and have the build/deploy process configured through there.  The 'runtimes' folder is certainly not a folder that exists in source control or my project folder.

'runtimes' folder contents:

[image: 'runtimes' folder contents]

example contents:

[image: example contents]

Thanks,
Drew

Comment: Trying to figure this out myself - not having any luck finding information in the official documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These exist because you are building your application as a self contained application as opposed to one that is dependent upon the framework being installed on the machine executing it.  Documentation can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/ describing the various options that can be used to control this output.

Comment: This link do not mention the 'runtimes' folder. In my case a FDD deployment (no runtime option), the runtimes folder is created.

Comment: How to filter specific environment line want to remove win-86

Comment: I think this anwser is wrong. This folder exists because you are creating a cross-platform application.

Answer (score 16):

Like @Gregory_Ott I was facing a similar issue where my deployment was an FDD deployment and the 'runtimes' folder was still being created. All I did was, mentioned the runtime and set the self-contained property to false.
In the following example I have used dotnet to publish:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o ..\publish --runtime win-x64 --self-contained false
```

The following link should help you with the deployment:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli

Answer (score 5):

Setting your RuntimeIdentifier might be the solution. In my case, working with an Azure Function, it cut about 500 megs and reduced my archive down to 174 megs. This is important because on Consumption plans you get very limited storage.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
  <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>

  <!-- 
  Prevents the runtimes folder from being created in publish, which contained 500 megs of runtime files we  don't need.
  -->
  <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>    
  <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 3):

If **portable** target runtime is selected, `runtime` folder is created.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I was facing this situation with a .NET 5 application. An empty "runtimes" project was there in the output directory. After wasting a few minutes I realized that the folder was a left-over from a previous build. I deleted bin/obj folders completely and published again and the "runtimes" folder is no longer there in the output. I didn't have to change anything in the project file or build options. Hope it saves someone else a few minutes too.

Answer (score 1):

Could this explain the existence of a runtimes folder in an **FDD** deployment:

> A framework-dependent deployment with third-party dependencies is only
> as portable as its third-party dependencies. For example, if a
> third-party library only supports macOS, the app isn't portable to
> Windows systems. This happens if the third-party dependency itself
> depends on native code. A good example of this is Kestrel server,
> which requires a native dependency on libuv. **When an FDD is created
> for an application with this kind of third-party dependency, the
> published output contains a folder for each Runtime Identifier (RID)
> that the native dependency supports (and that exists in its NuGet
> package).**

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs?tabs=vs156#framework-dependent-deployment

Answer (score 1):

In the publish profile in Visual Studio, if Target runtime is set to 'Portable' then all possible runtimes are generated. This is the default, so the output can be reduced by a more selective choice if applicable:

[image]