# Superfluous 'runtimes' folder created in output directory for .NET 5 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-5

I've just migrated a (WPF) .NET 4.6 project to .NET 5.

I've noticed it is now creating a folder called 'runtimes' in the output directory with lots of platform-dependent dlls.

Since this app will only run on Windows machines, is there anyway of preventing these folders being created during a build in Visual Studio?

Comment: I was just fighting a related issue today. Do _not_ just delete the runtimes folder, because then the runtime might pick the assembly in the root folder, which does not have an implementation (every method just throws PlatformNotSupported)

Answer (score 19):

That's pretty easy to change: In your csproj file, inside the `PropertyGroup`, set the `SelfContained` property to "false" and specify a `RuntimeIdentifier`; like this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I found this on the runtime identifiers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog .

Comment: Thank you, the Output type of WinExe combined with the runtime identifier cleaned up all the unnecessary dll's I was being plagued with.

Answer (score 0):

The runtime folder contains all the necessary files to run your application regardless your target platform. You can specify to publish a [single file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file), but this is the way the new framework works.

This new way of producing the build artifact may seem counter intuitive. You may have a look at ['runtimes' Folder after Publishing a .Net Core App to Azure Publish Via VS Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755276/runtimes-folder-after-publishing-a-net-core-app-to-azure-publish-via-vs-online)

Comment: It looks like the app is being published as a 'Self contained deployment' rather than a 'framework dependent deployment', however I see no option to change this?

Comment: if you choose 'self-contained' then 'Produce single file' you should have a single file. (if I read correctly your comment)