# ASP Web API Large Runtimes Folder

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have 2 projects, an ASP MVC project and an ASP Web API project using .NET Framework 4.7.2

From a coding perspective both of these project types are very similar.

Yet the MVC project publishes to <100MB and the API project to 500MB+, despite the MVC project containing numerous JS libraries and other content.

This seems to be down to a folder the Web API project includes called "runtimes". Is this folder necessary, can it be optionalised, are there some optimisation options I can set?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67920055/superfluous-runtimes-folder-created-in-output-directory-for-net-5-project

Answer (score 1):

This is the framework which is published because of the settings in your publish profile.

> Publishing your app as self-contained produces an application that includes the .NET runtime and libraries, and your application and its dependencies. Users of the application can run it on a machine that doesn't have the .NET runtime installed.
> Publishing your app as framework-dependent produces an application that includes only your application itself and its dependencies. Users of the application have to separately install the .NET runtime.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: I am using .NET Frameword 4.7.2 not .NET Core using the standard File System publish method. There are not options I can see which match your answer.